# Question about conditions for conservative field

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields

Question about conditions for conservative field
In common textbooks' discussions about conservative vector field. There is always two assumptions about the region concerned, namely the region is simply connected and open.

Usually in textbooks there is not much explanations on why these assumptions are necessary, no proof is given on why conservative field is not possible if the region is not simply connected or not open.

I wonder whether these two assumptions are just for computational convenience or it is really logically not possible to have a conservative field in region that is not simply connected or is not open?

Comment: Those two conditions are sufficient but not necessary.  I saw a question the other day about how to prove that these do in fact imply conservation.  If you search for a bit you could probably find it.

Comment: Usually you want to identify global properties (e.g., having a vanishing line integral along any closed curve, or admitting a scalar potential) with local properties (e.g., having vanishing curl at each point).  You can't do this if the region isn't open and simply connected.  If it's not open, then derivatives aren't defined on the boundaries.  If it's not simply connected, then the vector field can be curl-free but still not "conservative" in the global sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Simple-connectedness**

It is certainly possible to have a conservative vector field on a set that is not simply connected: Pick any non-simply connected set $U$ and any differentiable function $f: U \subset \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$; then, by definition, the vector field $$\nabla f := \left\langle \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^1}, \ldots, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^n} \right\rangle$$ is conservative. (By definition, all examples arise this way.)

An key result involving conservative vector fields that relies on simple-connectedness is the following:

> **Theorem** A vector field ${\bf F} = \langle P, Q \rangle$ defined on an open, **simply connected** subset $U \subseteq \Bbb R^2$ is conservative iff $$\phantom{(\ast)} \qquad \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = 0. \qquad (\ast)$$

The idea here is that one can recover a potential function $f$ for $\bf F$ by choosing a base point $p \in U$, choosing for each $q \in U$ a path $\gamma$ from $p$ to $q$ and defining
$$f(q) := \int_{\gamma} {\bf F} \cdot d{\bf s}.$$
Then, since $\bf F$ satisfies $(\ast)$, [Green's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem) guarantees that this definition of $f(q)$ is independent of the only choice we made, namely the path $\gamma$; doing this for every point $q \in U$ defines a function that, by construction, is a potential for $\bf F$.

This theorem fails, however, when we omit the hypothesis of simple connectedness: For example, the so-called *vortex vector field*
$${\bf V} := \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2} \langle -y, x\rangle$$
defined on $\Bbb R^2 - \{ 0 \}$ (which is not simply connected) satisfies $(\ast)$ but it is not conservative: For any circular path $C$ oriented anticlockwise and enclosing the origin, we have
$$\int_C {\bf V} \cdot d{\bf s} = 2 \pi.$$ (Try showing this yourself; evaluating this integral is easiest when $C$ is centered at the origin.) So, we can see that simple-connectedness really is essential for this result and some that depend on it. (Note, by the way, that Green's Theorem implies that the restriction of $\bf V$ to an simply connected subset *is* conservative; up to a suitable constant, any potential is a so-called *branch of the argument (function)*.)

*Remark* For vector fields $\bf F$ on subsets of $\Bbb R^3$, the appropriate replacement for $(\ast)$ is that $\text{curl } {\bf F} = 0$ (the scalar components of this equation are each similar to $(\ast)$); there are similar conditions on higher-dimensional Euclidean spaces.

**Openness**

The requirement of openness is more technical. In short, it ensures that one can always (attempt to) take derivatives of functions: In short, if we want to differentiate a function (or vector field) at a point, as we need to do in many cases, including the above theorem, we must be able to compare the its value at a point with nearby points, and openness is simply the requirement that all sufficiently nearby points are already in the domain. This requirement is also less essential than simple-connectedness in that in many cases we can still produce reasonable results with weaker hypotheses on the domain at the cost of some technicality, namely, of making sense of derivatives when, a priori, one cannot compare values of the object being differentiated in all directions. For a particularly simple case of this, recall that we can define derivatives at the endpoints $a, b$ of functions $[a, b] \to \Bbb R$ simply by replacing the limit in the usual difference quotient with (respectively) the right-handed or left-handed limit.

Comment: thanks. just one more question. As an example could you give a vector function in a non-simply connected region that is conservative?

Comment: @KelvinS You're welcome, I hope you found it useful. As mentioned at the beginning of the post, you can produce such examples easily, just by taking the gradient of any continuously differentiable function with domain a non-simply connected set. (In fact, by definition *all* such examples are of this sort.)