# Conservative field defined over a not simply-connected region

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

I am wondering if a field can be conservative if the region where it is defined is not simply-connected. By definition $F$ is conservative if there exists a differentiable function which satisfies $F=grad(u)$ If I find such function which is defined in the not simply connected region, am I OK?

Comment: When you ask "am I OK?" are you asking "is the integral of this field along any closed path zero"?  This is a common useful property of conservative fields on simply-connected domains.

Comment: Yes I am asking this. And I think that a field is conservative and the integral on every closed path is zero are equivalent statements.

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1299098/question-about-conditions-for-conservative-field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what is your concern. It is perfectly valid to ask for a vector field to be equal to a gradient of some function. Let me explain briefly why simple connectedness comes up in the study of conservative vector fields. Whenever you have a vector field which is a gradient, it has vanishing curl. In simply-connected regions the converse is true: every vector field whose curl vanishes is a gradient. This implication in general fails to be true in domains which are not simply connected.

Comment: I am asking can a field be potential(conservative) if the region where it is defined is not simply connected?

Comment: It can. Why not? In fact restriction of a conservative vector field on $\mathbb R^n$ to any open subset will still be a conservative.

Comment: And if it is is it true that the integral on every closed path in the region is equal to zero?

Comment: Yes, this is always true if you have a conservative vector field (but not if you demand only that curl vanishes, which is a weaker condition in non simply-connected regions).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for example $X=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is $\mathrm{grad}\,u$ on $\mathbb{R}^2-\{(0,0)\}$, where $u(x,y)=x$.